# SSLPeerUnverifiedException: peer not authenticated

Tags: java, httpclient

Yet again, the dreary Problem of SSLPeerUnverified, but I'm not using self signed certificates.
I try to connect to a host using https. This host has a correct certificate, neither Firefox nor HttpsUrlConnection has any problems with it.
However trying to connect using HttpClient, I get the dreaded exception.

Any clues? Or tip where to look closer?

Thanks!

Edit: Debug output

main, handling exception:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: 
sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: 
unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

main, IOException in getSession():

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: 
PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: 
unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

Answer (score 40):

It seems that you need to import the certificate into the trusted keystore your JVM is using. If you are not using a different trusted keystore in your application this will be "cacerts".

You can follow a step by step guide at "[How to Fix 'SSLPeerUnverifiedException: peer not authenticated' Exception in Groovy / Java](http://nerd-ability.blogspot.co.uk/2013/01/tech-how-to-fix-sslpeerunverifiedexcept.html) ".

Short version:

1. Run the following command, replace `$ADDRESS` with the URL, minus the "https://":

   ```
   echo -n | openssl s_client -connect $ADDRESS:443 | \
     sed -ne '/-BEGIN CERTIFICATE-/,/-END CERTIFICATE-/p' > /tmp/$ADDRESS.cert
   ```
2. Run the following command, replace `$ALIAS` a short name for the key, `$ADDRESS` with the cert name from above, `$PATH` with the path to cacerts in your JRE.

   ```
    sudo keytool -importcert -alias "$ALIAS" -file /tmp/$ADDRESS.cert \
      -keystore $PATH/cacerts -storepass changeit
   ```

Comment: 2 days of suffering ended with this answer. Take your vote good man.