# How to Create Folder in DropBox using Temboo API

Tags: dropbox, dropbox-api, java, temboo

I want to upload and download files to any cloud from my desktop Java application. I searched on web and found about Temboo. I tried to use it and write some code to create a sample folder in my DropBox account.

I created an App in my DropBox and got App Key and App Secret. Then I used https://live.temboo.com/library/Library/Dropbox/FileOperations/CreateFolder/ OAUTH wizard and got my Access Token and Access Token Secret. Now, I try to run below code to create a Folder with the name "Test"

```
CreateFolder createFolder = new com.temboo.Library.Dropbox.FileOperations.CreateFolder(session);


    CreateFolder.CreateFolderInputSet createFolderInput = createFolder.newInputSet();

    createFolderInput.set_NewFolderName(DROPBOX_BACKUP_FOLDERNAME); 

    createFolderInput.set_AppKey(DROPBOX_APP_KEY);
    createFolderInput.set_AppSecret(DROPBOX_APP_SECRET);
    createFolderInput.set_AccessToken(DROPBOX_ACCESS_TOKEN);
    createFolderInput.set_AccessTokenSecret(DROPBOX_ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET);

    createFolder.execute(createFolderInput);
```

And When I run above code it is throwing exception on:

```
   createFolder.execute(createFolderInput);
```

Please have a look at exceptions:

```
com.temboo.core.TembooException: peer not authenticated
at com.temboo.core.TembooSession.postContent(TembooSession.java:168)
at com.temboo.core.Choreography.executeWithResults(Choreography.java:88)
at                                                               com.temboo.Library.Dropbox.FileOperations.CreateFolder.execute(CreateFolder.java:50)
at TestPackage.DropBoxCloudServer.createFolder(DropBoxCloudServer.java:55)
at TestPackage.DropBoxCloudServer.main(DropBoxCloudServer.java:20)
 Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: peer not authenticated
at               com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSessionImpl.getPeerCertificates(SSLSessionImpl.java:352)
at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.AbstractVerifier.verify(AbstractVerifier.java:128)
at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:339)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:123)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:147)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:108)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:415)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:641)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:576)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:554)
at com.temboo.core.TembooSession.postContent(TembooSession.java:151)
... 4 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi I just found solution to this by myself.. I just updated my Java to latest JDK version and it is working f9.. appart from this I need to add

```
createFolderInput.set_Root("sandbox");
```

to my code .. It is now working perfect ..

Answer (score 0):

I work at Temboo.

It looks like you're running into an SSL Cert issue in your local dev environment. There's some good advice in this related question:

[SSLPeerUnverifiedException: peer not authenticated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12961570/sslpeerunverifiedexception-peer-not-authenticated)

Hopefully that gets you up and running with Dropbox + Temboo. Please don't hesitate to let me know if it doesn't and we'll continue to investigate.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable time. I am running my app in Windows so can you please suggest me how to shortout this in windows ..

Comment: Here's another approach that looks like it should work regardless of your operating system: http://javaskeleton.blogspot.com/2010/07/avoiding-peer-not-authenticated-with.html

Comment: I am not able to solve this.. I am not using web application.. it is simply a class file which I run through my netbeans ide. Please help me .. I tried to implement above methods but its all not working for me.

Comment: Since this is an issue with your local development environment, I recommend trying again from another IDE or resetting your current IDE to clear out any old config settings that may have gotten messed up.

Comment: Hi @Cormac thanks for your help.. finally I get rid of my problem .. I am unable to find suitable example for uploading file to dropbox and download from dropbox .. please can you provide me link..

Comment: Please send us an email (support@temboo.com) so we can discuss this in more detail than the comments here allow - thanks!