# Can't access secured (HTTPS) website using burpsuite and firefox as browser

Tags: firefox, ssl-certificate, opentest

I'm trying to access HTTPS website like facebook and google i'm using burpsuite to intercept the flow and it failed at each times

here is what i tried : i imported burp suite CA into firefox browser /refreshed firefox several times / tried this solution that i found on stack : [SSLPeerUnverifiedException: peer not authenticated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12961570/sslpeerunverifiedexception-peer-not-authenticated?fbclid=IwAR0Z_s2ra8-o37U_bgjLSGK127cIAL09HviQG3-KLnvnLiHKV-G8lpB8e0M)
i changed parrot OS from 4.4 to 4.5 i changed java version to 11.0.1

The result in browser when try to acceed Peer not authentificated i expected to get facebook page

In alert panel i have this : javax.net.ssl.SslPeerUnverifiedException:peer not authenticated

Answer (score 0):

Did you install Burp's CA Certificate in your browser? If not, follow these instructions: https://support.portswigger.net/customer/portal/articles/1783075-installing-burp-s-ca-certificate-in-your-browser