# WSO2 - Unable to sendViaPost to url

Tags: wso2, apache-axis, esb, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-esb

I'm using WSO2 ESB to send JSON message using call mediator to Bitrix CRM. I had a look to all the posts and tutorials and I get always the same error:
HTTPSender - Unable to sendViaPost to url
After i switched Bitrix24 to use Nginx Push I have following problem on ESB.

```
TID[-1234] [EI] [2020-02-11 07:04:01,702] INFO {org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPSender} - Unable to sendViaPost to url[https://xxxx.com/rest/update?id=33826] 
org.opensaml.ws.soap.client.http.TLSProtocolSocketFactory.verifyHostname(TLSProtocolSocketFactory.java:233) 
org.opensaml.ws.soap.client.http.TLSProtocolSocketFactory.createSocket(TLSProtocolSocketFactory.java:194) 
org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpConnection.open(HttpConnection.java:707) 
org.apache.commons.httpclient.MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager$HttpConnectionAdapter.open(MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager.java:1361) 
org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeWithRetry(HttpMethodDirector.java:387) org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeMethod(HttpMethodDirector.java:171) 
org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:397) 
org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AbstractHTTPSender.executeMethod(AbstractHTTPSender.java:704)
 org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPSender.sendViaPost(HTTPSender.java:199) 
org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPSender.send(HTTPSender.java:81) 
org.apache.axis2.transport.http.CommonsHTTPTransportSender.writeMessageWithCommons(CommonsHTTPTransportSender.java:459) 
org.apache.axis2.transport.http.CommonsHTTPTransportSender.invoke(CommonsHTTPTransportSender.java:286) 
org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.send(AxisEngine.java:442) 
org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.send(OutInAxisOperation.java:441) 
org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.executeImpl(OutInAxisOperation.java:227) org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient.execute(OperationClient.java:149) 
org.apache.synapse.message.senders.blocking.BlockingMsgSender.sendReceive(BlockingMsgSender.java:490)
 org.apache.synapse.message.senders.blocking.BlockingMsgSender.send(BlockingMsgSender.java:382) 
org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2FlexibleMEPClient.send(Axis2FlexibleMEPClient.java:88) 
org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2Sender.sendOn(Axis2Sender.java:85) 
org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.send(Axis2SynapseEnvironment.java:547) 
org.apache.synapse.endpoints.AbstractEndpoint.send(AbstractEndpoint.java:384) 
org.apache.synapse.endpoints.HTTPEndpoint.send(HTTPEndpoint.java:85) 
org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.CallMediator.handleBlockingCall(CallMediator.java:164) 
org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.CallMediator.mediate(CallMediator.java:119) 
org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:108) 
org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:70) 
org.apache.synapse.config.xml.AnonymousListMediator.mediate(AnonymousListMediator.java:37) 
org.apache.synapse.mediators.filters.FilterMediator.mediate(FilterMediator.java:203) 
org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:108) 
org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:70) 
org.apache.synapse.mediators.filters.FilterMediator.mediate(FilterMediator.java:169) 
org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:108) 
org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:70) 
org.apache.synapse.mediators.filters.FilterMediator.mediate(FilterMediator.java:169) 
org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:108) 
org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:70) 
org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator.mediate(SequenceMediator.java:158) 
org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.ForEachMediator.mediateSequence(ForEachMediator.java:183) 
org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.ForEachMediator.mediate(ForEachMediator.java:145) 
org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:108) 
org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:70) 
org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator.mediate(SequenceMediator.java:158) 
org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.ProxyServiceMessageReceiver.receive(ProxyServiceMessageReceiver.java:224) 
org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180) 
org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.processEntityEnclosingRequest(ServerWorker.java:415) 
org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.run(ServerWorker.java:151) 
org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172) 
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) 
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) 
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

My call mediator looks like:

```
 <property description="messageType JSON"
                                           name="messageType"
                                           scope="axis2"
                                           type="STRING"
                                           value="application/json"/>
                                 <call blocking="true">
                                    <endpoint>
                                       <http method="POST"
                                             statistics="enable"
                                             trace="enable"
                                             uri-template="{uri.var.RESTURL}">
                                          <suspendOnFailure>
                                             <errorCodes>400</errorCodes>
                                             <initialDuration>0</initialDuration>
                                             <progressionFactor>1.0</progressionFactor>
                                             <maximumDuration>0</maximumDuration>
                                          </suspendOnFailure>
                                       </http>
                                    </endpoint>
                                 </call>
```

I've tried to send same message using Postman and It worked fine. 
Thanks for any help.

**UPDATE**

Logs in admin panel are not full. I've checked manually on server and the problem is with:
`javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: peer not authenticated`

**UPDATE2**

Full stack:

```
[2020-02-11 22:18:01,953] [EI-Core]  INFO - HTTPSender Unable to sendViaPost to url[https:/xxxx.com/rest/7]
javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: peer not authenticated
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSessionImpl.getPeerCertificates(SSLSessionImpl.java:450)
        at org.apache.commons.httpclient.protocol.SSLProtocolSocketFactory.verifyHostName(SSLProtocolSocketFactory.java:276)
        at org.apache.commons.httpclient.protocol.SSLProtocolSocketFactory.createSocket(SSLProtocolSocketFactory.java:186)
        at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpConnection.open(HttpConnection.java:707)
        at org.apache.commons.httpclient.MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager$HttpConnectionAdapter.open(MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager.java:1361)
        at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeWithRetry(HttpMethodDirector.java:387)
        at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeMethod(HttpMethodDirector.java:171)
        at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:397)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AbstractHTTPSender.executeMethod(AbstractHTTPSender.java:704)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPSender.sendViaPost(HTTPSender.java:199)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPSender.send(HTTPSender.java:81)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.CommonsHTTPTransportSender.writeMessageWithCommons(CommonsHTTPTransportSender.java:459)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.CommonsHTTPTransportSender.invoke(CommonsHTTPTransportSender.java:286)
        at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.send(AxisEngine.java:442)
        at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.send(OutInAxisOperation.java:441)
        at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.executeImpl(OutInAxisOperation.java:227)
        at org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient.execute(OperationClient.java:149)
        at org.apache.synapse.message.senders.blocking.BlockingMsgSender.sendReceive(BlockingMsgSender.java:490)
        at org.apache.synapse.message.senders.blocking.BlockingMsgSender.send(BlockingMsgSender.java:382)
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2FlexibleMEPClient.send(Axis2FlexibleMEPClient.java:88)
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2Sender.sendOn(Axis2Sender.java:85)
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.send(Axis2SynapseEnvironment.java:547)
        at org.apache.synapse.endpoints.AbstractEndpoint.send(AbstractEndpoint.java:384)
        at org.apache.synapse.endpoints.HTTPEndpoint.send(HTTPEndpoint.java:85)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.CallMediator.handleBlockingCall(CallMediator.java:164)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.CallMediator.mediate(CallMediator.java:119)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:108)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:70)
        at org.apache.synapse.config.xml.AnonymousListMediator.mediate(AnonymousListMediator.java:37)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.filters.FilterMediator.mediate(FilterMediator.java:203)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:108)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:70)
        at org.apache.synapse.config.xml.AnonymousListMediator.mediate(AnonymousListMediator.java:37)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.filters.FilterMediator.mediate(FilterMediator.java:203)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:108)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:70)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.filters.FilterMediator.mediate(FilterMediator.java:169)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:108)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:70)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator.mediate(SequenceMediator.java:158)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.ForEachMediator.mediateSequence(ForEachMediator.java:183)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.ForEachMediator.mediate(ForEachMediator.java:145)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:108)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:70)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator.mediate(SequenceMediator.java:158)
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.ProxyServiceMessageReceiver.receive(ProxyServiceMessageReceiver.java:224)
        at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.processEntityEnclosingRequest(ServerWorker.java:415)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.run(ServerWorker.java:151)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: Seems like you have missed out the Exception that is thrown. Can you share it as well? It seems to be a SSLPeerUnverifiedException.

Comment: @ArunanSugunakumar I've checked manually on server and it's related to: 
javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: peer not authenticated

Comment: so the server requires mutual ssl authentication? In that case - did you have the correct client key/certificate un your keystore?

Comment: @gusto2 It's dev server, how to disable that verification?

Comment: It's on the server side, if it's nginx, you may look for `ClientAuth` directive (as far I recall)

Comment: @gusto2 But if I can send a message from postman to external WS and then problem doesn't occur it's really not possible to somehow disable peer verification on WSO2 which sends message to the same WS a I send to from postman?

Comment: I was asking you if mutual ssl is enabled. if it's not, maybe the service server's certificate is not trusted (it would help if you'd share the whole stacktrace). please make sure the server's certificate issuer is trusted in the truststore `client-truststore.jks` see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12961570/sslpeerunverifiedexception-peer-not-authenticated

Comment: @gusto2 I've updated main post with full stack, i've also added cert like on link that you've provided and I strill have same error :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be a known [issue](https://github.com/wso2/product-ei/issues/1501) in Call mediator blocking="true" mode. Please try out the work around suggested in the issue.

> As a workaround for this, we can disable switching to opensaml http
>   client by setting rampart.axiom.parser.pool=false in a server start
>   up.